# Inject a link that runs a JavaScript function into a website using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I want to inject a link at the end of this webpage.

[Website](http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425)

The link will cycle from one record to the other adding a +1 at the end of the link so when clicking next the link will change from `http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425` to `http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5426` etc..

For this purpose I created a HTML page with an iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><link href="includes/ls.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
<body bgcolor="#373536" >
<iframe 
 src="http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425"
 width="100%" height="500"
 sandbox>
  <p>
    <a href="http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425">
      Fallback link for browsers that, unlikely, don't support frames
    </a>
  </p>


</body>
</html>
```

The webpage when loaded is working fine. However, I don't want to use an iframe. So I though of creating a Chrome extension to inject the code.

I use this as manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
  "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": [
    "http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/inject.css"
      ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My inject.js code:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        // This part of the script triggers when page is done loading
        console.log("Hello. This message was sent from scripts/inject.js");
        // ----------------------------------------------------------

    }
    }, 10);
});

var c=5425;
var url="http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=";

function f(){ 
 document.getElementById("clicks").data = url+c;
 c++;
 }

var newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.innerHTML = 'Next>';
newlink.setAttribute('id','clicks');
newlink.setAttribute('title', 'Next>');
newlink.onclick = f;
newlink.setAttribute('onclick',"f()");
document.body.appendChild(newlink);
```

However, when the extension is run I am getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined" error on the page

I have no idea how to fix it. I just want to add a link that cycle from one record to another.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Who raise this error ? the page or the injected content script ?

Comment: The page i think: `Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined onclick @ popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425:1`

Comment: Try to use addListner instead of puting thé évent handler un the onclick attribute ?

Comment: I added `newlink.addEventListener("click", "f()");` the error is gone but the link is not working...

Comment: It's more something like `newLink.addEventListener("click", f)`

Comment: No still doesn't work and a new error appears `Uncaught ReferenceError: newLink is not defined`

Comment: I have misspelled : `newlink.addEventListener("click", f)`

Comment: I know but it still does not work, there is no error but the script seems not running!

Comment: it looked like the function f is not running...

Comment: Have you tried setting `f` as a variable? like `var f = function(...)`?

Comment: Yes i also tried this. no luck

Comment: What is the `.data = ...` ? If you want to change the URL of thé link I think it's `.href = ...`

Comment: The `.data` was a mistake since i copy paste it from a div and i forgot to change it!! Now we are getting somewhere, when i click the link for the first type the link changes from `http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425` to `http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5425` as expected. However, when i click on next a second time it doesn't work

Comment: It seems it works if i fast click on the link several times before the page is fully loaded. However, if the pages is fully loaded and i clicked on the link it returns to 'http://lcsyndicate.com.lb/web/popupGuide.aspx?Guide_Id=5426'

Comment: It's because the content script is loaded every time you load the page. So `var c=5425;` is executed after each page reload.

Comment: How can i change it so it is only loaded once?